# KDTree Python implementation detail

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, scipy, binary-tree

I'm looking into KDTree implementation in scipy library and found myself a little bit confusing by this lines https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py#L314-L319

```
side_distances = np.maximum(0,np.maximum(x-self.maxes,self.mins-x))
if p != np.inf:
    side_distances **= p
    min_distance = np.sum(side_distances)
else:
    min_distance = np.amax(side_distances)
```

Could someone explain why initial `min_distance` is calculated that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min_distance` is the [*p*-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#p-norm) of `side_distances`, which in turn is the distance along each dimension from `x` to the bounding box (with interior). In other words, `min_distance` is the distance from `x` to the closest point of the bounding box.

Comment: Why do we initialize `side_distances` in such a way: `side_distances = np.maximum(0,np.maximum(x-self.maxes,self.mins-x))` ? In particular, why we do `x-self.maxes` but not vice versa?

Comment: @PavelPodlipensky That's a convoluted way to say that, if `x` is greater than `max`, return `x - max`, else if `x` is less than `min`, return `min - x`, else return `0`.